# Meaning of SS command output with 3 colons (':::')?

Tags: parsing, ss

The increasingly popular ss command (/usr/sbin/ss on RHEL) is a replacement for netstat.

I'm trying to parse the output in Python and I'm seeing some odd data that is not explained in the documentation.

```
$ ss -an | head
State    Recv-Q Send-Q    Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port
LISTEN   0      0                    :::14144               :::*
LISTEN   0      0             127.0.0.1:32000                *:*
LISTEN   0      0                    :::3233                :::*
LISTEN   0      0                     *:5634                 *:*
LISTEN   0      0                    :::5634                :::*
```

So, it's obvious what the local address means when it's 127.0.0.1:32000, obviously listening on the loopback interface on port 32000. But, what do the 3 colons ::: mean?

Really, I can figure it's two extra colons, since the format is host:port, so **what does a host of two colons mean?**

I should mention I'm running this on a RHEL/CENTOS box:

```
Linux boxname 2.6.18-348.3.1.el5 #1 SMP somedate x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is not explained in **any** of the online man pages or other discussions I can find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's [IPV6 abbreviated address representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation). The colon groups represent consecutive zero groups.

:::14144 would be read as 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 port 14144 which I guess would mean all addresses with port 14144

:::* would be read as 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 all ports which I guess would mean all addresses with any port